# I am trying to append a dictionary to a list. but it showing me Name error and Traceback error. I tried editing the name but still the same

Tags: python-3.x, nameerror

This is what I am trying to implement.

Complete the Category class in budget.py. It should be able to instantiate objects based on different budget categories like food, clothing, and entertainment. When objects are created, they are passed in the name of the category. The class should have an instance variable called ledger that is a list. The class should also contain the following methods:

A deposit method that accepts an amount and description. If no description is given, it should default to an empty string. The method should append an object to the ledger list in the form of {"amount": amount, "description": description}.

and my code is

```
class Category:
    ledger =[]
    
    def __init__(self,category):
        print(category)
       

    def deposit(self,amount,description):
        
        self.amount=amount
        self.description=description
        if not description:
            return ""
        else:
        
            dect={"amount":self.amount,"description":self.description}
            print(dect)
            ledger.append(dect)
            self.ledger=ledger
            print(self.ledger)
food=Category("food")
food.deposit(1000,"initial deposit")
```

```
but when I am executing it I am getting error message.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Python/budject_app.py", line 23, in <module>
    food.deposit(1000,"initial deposit")
  File "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Python/budject_app.py", line 19, in deposit
    ledger.append(dect)
NameError: name 'ledger' is not defined

I don't see a typo in the name and tried different things but still it is not working.
```

Comment: Try refer to `ledger.append(dect)` with `self.ledger.append(dect)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `self.ledger` in `__init__`, rather than use `ledger` outside.

code:

```
class Category:
    
    def __init__(self,category):
        self.ledger =[]
        print(category)
       
    def deposit(self,amount,description):
        self.amount=amount
        self.description=description
        if not description:
            return ""
        else:
            dect={"amount":self.amount,"description":self.description}
            print(dect)
            self.ledger.append(dect)
            # self.ledger=ledger
            print(self.ledger)

food=Category("food")
food.deposit(1000,"initial deposit")
food.deposit(2000,"second deposit")
```

result:

```
food
{'amount': 1000, 'description': 'initial deposit'}
[{'amount': 1000, 'description': 'initial deposit'}]
{'amount': 2000, 'description': 'second deposit'}
[{'amount': 1000, 'description': 'initial deposit'}, {'amount': 2000, 'description': 'second deposit'}]
```

BTW, you dont need use `self.amount` and `self.description` if you dont need use them in other `Category` methods.

code:

```
class Category:
    
    def __init__(self,category):
        self.ledger =[]
        print(category)
       
    def deposit(self,amount,description):
        if not description:
            return ""
        else:
            dect={"amount":amount,"description":description}
            print(dect)
            self.ledger.append(dect)
            print(self.ledger)

food=Category("food")
food.deposit(1000,"initial deposit")
food.deposit(2000,"second deposit")
```

result:

```
food
{'amount': 1000, 'description': 'initial deposit'}
[{'amount': 1000, 'description': 'initial deposit'}]
{'amount': 2000, 'description': 'second deposit'}
[{'amount': 1000, 'description': 'initial deposit'}, {'amount': 2000, 'description': 'second deposit'}]
```